# OpenXML preserving formats on break lines (problems)

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm having serious problems with the breaks in a Word document generation.

this is my library funcion I'm using for send text in a BookMark:

```
    public void sentText(string _BkMk, string _text, bool _break, RunProperties _rProp)
    {  
            Text text = new Text(_text) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
            Run run = new Run(new RunProperties(_rProp));   

            run.Append(text);

            Run run2 = new Run();               

            if (_break)
            {                  
               run2.Append(new Break());
               //CarriageReturn cr = new CarriageReturn();
               //run2.Append(cr);                   
            }

            foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in bookmarkMap.Values)
            {
                if (bookmarkStart.Name.Value == _BkMk)
                {
                    bookmarkStart.InsertBeforeSelf(run);
                    if (_break)
                    {
                        bookmarkStart.InsertBeforeSelf(run2);
                    }
                }
            }
```

in the runProperties cames the font, size, etc...
The biggest problem is when I send diferent strings in the same Bookmark and I need to leave a line space.  I send a empty string, or a space like " "  and the result is a empty line, but with a diferent font (TimesNewRoman) and size (12). For me is really important to preserve the font size in this empty lines...

Some idea?

Comment: why I can't do that?: Run run2 = new Run(new RunProperties(_rProp)); when I Run the code It says that the element is from a tree... For the moment I create another function InsertBlank(string _BkMk, RunProperties _rProp) where I do this new Break whith the run properties I want(here I can do that)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of leaving comments with important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and all you want is a blank line then all you have to do is insert a blank paragraph and it should follow the default font that you have setup. This will require you to split up your text across two different paragraphs with two different runs in order to work:

```
public void sentText(string _BkMk, string _text, bool _break, RunProperties _rProp)
{  
     Text text = new Text(_text) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };

     Run run = new Run(new RunProperties(_rProp));          
     run.Append(text);                    

     Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
     paragraph1.Append(run);

     foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in bookmarkMap.Values)
     {
         if (bookmarkStart.Name.Value == _BkMk)
         {
             bookmarkStart.InsertBeforeSelf(paragraph1);
             if (_break)
             {
                 bookmarkStart.InsertBeforeSelf(paragraph1);
                 bookmarkStart.InsertBeforeSelf(new Paragraph());
             }
         }
     }
}
```

I would also recommend using paragraphs instead of just runs since Word will create an empty paragraph when you hit the enter key.